# Correct approach to adding to FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Searching around for the correct, or best way to add an item to a flatlist

my first approach was to simple add an item to the state.. so I tried this:

```
var NewObject = {};
NewObject.Name = "New Object";
this.setState({
    Data: [...this.state.Data, ...[NewObject]]
});
```

However, doing this causes everything in the list to be readded it seems, and i get all sorts of key errors.

is this.state.Data.push(NewObject); the approach? that dosen't seem to allow a reload

any help would be huge!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
this.setState({Data: [...this.state.Data, newObject]})
```

And there is an 'extraData' prop in flatlist. Use it to notify flatlist about any changes in its datasource.

```
<FlatList
...
extraData={this.state.Data}
...
>
```

this.state.Data.push(NewObject) mutates the state directly, never do that.

P.s You can also set parent component of FlatList as PureComponent for better performance.