# FlatList not rerendering

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, rerender

I made a simple FlatList in react native to get a list of bets. While the pull to refresh is working, it was not rerendering the FlatList. I then learnt of the extraData props but passing it this.state.refreshing or even this.state is not triggering the rerendering of the FlatList. This seems to be an android issue only as people reported this to work on iOS but I'm still missing a solution for that matter.

```
class BetList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bets: [],
            refreshing: false
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this._loadBetList();
    }

    _loadBetList() {
        console.log("Fetching...");
        Api.getAllBets().then((res) => {
            res = res.map((item) => {
                return ({key: item.id + ""});
            });
            this.setState({bets: res});
        });
    }

    _onRefresh() {
        console.log("Refreshing...");
        this.setState({refreshing: true}, () => this._loadBetList());
        this.setState( {refreshing: false} );
    }

    render() {
        const { bets } = this.state;

        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={bets}
                    extraData={this.state}
                    renderItem={({item}) =>
                        <BetListItem id={item.key}/>
                    }
                    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                    onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh()}
                />
                <ResetAnswersButtonComponent/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default BetList;
```

Comment: As far as I know, extraData prop must change in order to refresh flatlist. Did you track your extraData value?

Comment: The refreshing state does change to true when I pull to refresh. And yet extraData does not seem to see it.

Comment: When i faced the same problem, I just tried to give simple number data (`let count = 0;`) to extraData prob and added 1 on each service or when I refreshed the page. I did not use state and It worked.

Answer (score 0):

First add a key to the component that renderItem method returns

e.g.

```
<BetListItem id={item.key} key = {item.key}/>
```

Also

the `onRefresh` and `loadMore` functions can be modified as below

```
_loadBetList() {
        console.log("Fetching...");
        Api.getAllBets().then((res) => {
            res = res.map((item) => {
                return ({key: item.id + ""});
            });
            this.setState({bets: res,refreshing : false});
        });
    }     

_onRefresh() {
        console.log("Refreshing...");
        this.setState({refreshing: true}, () => this._loadBetList());
    }
```

Comment: What am I supposed to do with the key I'm passing to my rendered item? Also my SetState for refreshing was initially there already, I just moved it to see if it was impacting anything for extraData.

Comment: The Key prop is not for your render component to use, It is used by react.               https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Pardon me if i my answer sounded rude,

Comment: I see. It's ok I didn't take it for rude. But it does not change anything to add that key prop.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you ?, i have never seen a function executing in the state...

```
_onRefresh() {
        console.log("Refreshing...");
        this.setState({refreshing: true}, () => this._loadBetList());
        this.setState( {refreshing: false} );
    }
```

try changing it to

```
_onRefresh() {
        console.log("Refreshing...");
        this.setState({refreshing: true});
        this._loadBetList();
        this.setState( {refreshing: false} );
    }
```

Oh , and componentDidMount is async for some reason but you are not using the await keyword anywhere... change _loadBetList and _onRefresh() to async , and leave componentDidMound sync.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this._loadBetList();
    }

    async _loadBetList() {
        console.log("Fetching...");
        var res = await Api.getAllBets()
        res = res.map((item) => {
                return ({key: item.id + ""});
            });
        this.setState({bets: res})
    }

    async _onRefresh() {
        console.log("Refreshing...");
        this.setState({refreshing: true});
        await this._loadBetList()
        this.setState( {refreshing: false} );
    }
```

Comment: It does work using it as callback. I just followed what people were doing they don't really explain why they do it this way. Your edit does not make it work tho, but it does make a smoother first rendering.

Comment: I didn't knew it worked that way :o, however, i'm on android and when i call setstate the whole thing rerenders, maybe you can call directly to the state instead of using a const in the render function and delete extradata `data={this.state.bets}`

Comment: Does it? I just did it, I just have my "Refreshin" and "Fetching" print but not the "Fetching" for every listItem showing that they're being rerendered.

Comment: Yes it does, i made a simple example using your code, i used a different api but the rest is the same https://snack.expo.io/S1LgAX9fN

Comment: This is weird 'cause if I add rows in my db it will not create new listItem.

Comment: Then the problem is in the function that handles new rows, it should get this.state.bets , add it with .concat or .push , and use setstate again , the whole flatlist should rerender, you can also use this way of updating state https://stackoverflow.com/a/48821341/10205629 . May be your code that's messing things up

Comment: Wait actually I just rechecked, it does create/delete items now, but it doesn't rerender those already existing.

Comment: for rerendering all the items you should store this.state.bets in a variable, then push a new item, then use setState in bets , all the flatlist rerenders that way , again ... that's how flatlist work, you are doing something wrong but now the question is offtopic, the code you posted works in the snack so please add the code that's not "working"